# No such module error while importing GoogleCast framework in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an ios application using swift. Downloaded the google cast frame work from the below link mentioned.
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads
Added this frame work in the application and imported like this:
import GoogleCast
But I am getting an error saying that "No Such module Google Cast"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got something working in Swift.
I did not need to import anything.

Did you follow instructions from https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender

And also configure Objective-C bridging header.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

I put the location of file `GoogleCast.h` here

[image]

I tested this sample code:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, GCKDeviceScannerListener {

    var scanner = GCKDeviceScanner()!;


    func deviceDidComeOnline(device: GCKDevice!) {
        println("device found - \(device.friendlyName)");
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //scanner = GCKDeviceScanner();


        println(scanner)
        scanner.addListener(self)

        scanner.startScan()
    }
}
```

I run this on an Iphone 5s from Xcode and it found my ChromeCast device:

`device found - AW`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I made it work on my Swift project(following Google Cast guide for iOS):

- I've downloaded [Google Cast iOS Sender SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_setup) and I pasted it inside my project's root folder
- I've set the **Other Linker Flags** in **Build Settings** to: `-ObjC -lc++`
- I've added the following framework libraries (linked, not embedded):

  1. Accelerate.framework
  2. AudioToolbox.framework
  3. AVFoundation.framework
  4. CoreBluetooth.framework
  5. CoreGraphics.framework
  6. CoreText.framework
  7. Foundation.framework
  8. MediaAccessibility.framework
  9. MediaPlayer.framework
  10. MediaToolbox.framework
  11. QuartzCore.framework
  12. SystemConfiguration.framework
  13. UIKit.framework
- Still under Linked framework libraries I've added GoogleCast.framework
  clicking on + -> Add Other... ->GoogleCast.framework
- I've added in the Build Phases of target a new entry in the Copy Bundle Resources section. I selected Add Other GoogleCast.framework -> Resources -> GoogleCastResources.bundle

I have not added any Objective-C bridging header and it worked great!